# Python lambda syntax

Tags: python, lambda

could anyone explain the syntax within lambda? I didn't get the indexing of x part.

```
L=[(19,1),(3,5),(9,2),(2,7),(13,1),(12,8),(5,2),(0,1),(9,4),(17,1),(8,2)]

L2=list(zip(L,range(len(L))))

L3=sorted(L2,key=lambda x:(x[0][1],-x[1]))
print(L3)
[y[0] for y in L3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but each element in L2 is tuple of the form `((x, y) z)` (x, y, and z are ints). That's what gets passed to the function in the second argument of `sorted()` (i.e. that's what the value of x "looks like"). So, the lambda returns

```py
x[0][1] = y # second element of inner tuple
x[1] = z # non-tuple second element of outer tuple
return (y, -z)
```

Comment: Btw, how do I know what L2 looks like? I tried it in the interpreter. Much quicker than unpacking that expression.

Comment: `L2` is a list; you can just look at it. Note that you don't *need* to call `list` explicitly. You can pass the `zip` instance to `sorted` directly.